# 1292, Truncated incorrect time value: (MySQL & Python)

Tags: python, mysql

We have developed a small program, where we want to take a value and search our MySQL database for other coincidences where a value is the same, at the same time. To do this, we are comparing time, and we use this SQL query:

```
value = pd.read_sql('SELECT third_temp_lpn FROM Raw_Validated WHERE TIME(time_end) = TIME("%s") AND third_temp_lpn = "%s"' % (x + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20), list_lpn_temp[-1]), conn).astype(float).values
```

Here, we use the TIME(time_end), which when used on our MySQL database works perfectly. The query is supposed to isolate time from datetime, and we set it equal to TIME(%s), which is our datetime in python (see full code).

When executing above query in python, we receive an odd error looking like this:

```
Warning: (1292, "Truncated incorrect time value: '2019-08-31'")
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

Anyone here who can help?

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pprint
import datetime
import math
from pandas.io import sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

list_lpn_temp = []
times = []
values = []

engine = create_engine("mysql://root:DTULab@123@localhost/Afgangsprojekt")
conn = engine.connect()

firstTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM Raw_Data', conn).astype(str).values.tolist()
firstTime = (pd.to_datetime(firstTime[0])-datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)).round('20T')

lastTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Raw_Data', conn).astype(str).values.tolist()
lastTime = (pd.to_datetime(lastTime[0])-datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)).round('20T')

print (firstTime[0])
print (lastTime[0])

index = pd.date_range(start=firstTime.min(), end=lastTime.max(), freq='20T')

for x in index:

    a_temp = pd.read_sql('SELECT temperature FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1" AND timestamp > "%s" AND timestamp < "%s" ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1' % (x, x+datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)), conn).astype(float).values
    a_temp = a_temp.astype(int)

    if a_temp:
        list_lpn_temp.extend(a_temp[0])
    else:
        print (x, " | ", x + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20))
        value = pd.read_sql('SELECT third_temp_lpn FROM Raw_Validated WHERE TIME(time_end) = TIME("%s") AND third_temp_lpn = "%s"' % (x + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20), list_lpn_temp[-1]), conn).astype(float).values
        time = pd.read_sql('SELECT time_end FROM Raw_Validated WHERE TIME(time_end) = TIME("%s") AND third_temp_lpn = "%s"' % (x + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20), list_lpn_temp[-1]), conn).astype(str).values
        values.append(value)
        times.append(time)
        print (values[0])
        print (times[0])
        list_lpn_temp.append(float('nan'))

print (list_lpn_temp)
```

Comment: Where is this `2019-08-31` value coming from? The `time_end` column?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, time_end = '2019-08-31 18:20:00' etc.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. We are isolating time from our datetime. time_end = '2019-08-31 18:20:00', and we only want "18:20:00". Are you saying our TIME() must be set as string?

Comment: What is the datatype of `time_end` column? If it is varchar you might have invalid datetime values there. `SELECT TIME('2019-08-31');` is supposed to produce a warning and wrong result instead of `00:00:00`.

Comment: Actually, the datatype on the database is TEXT (not good, I suppose)